# JavaScript draggable element moves erratically away from cursor during mouse drag operation

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, resize

I'm encountering an issue with the dragging functionality in my JavaScript application. I have implemented draggable elements using event listeners for mouse events (mousedown, mousemove, mouseup), but I'm experiencing erratic behavior where the draggable element moves far away from the cursor during the drag operation.

To see the issue, click on the black button to create a rectangle to drag.
The rectangle will move away from the mouse when dragging too.

```js
const DrawJs = {
    selectedShape: null,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    container: null,
    resizing: false,

    init: function (containerId) {
        const container = document.querySelector(containerId);
        this.container = container;
        return container;
    },

    drawRectangle: function (width, height, x, y, color) {
        const shape = document.createElement("div");
        shape.classList.add("resizable-shape");
        shape.style.width = width + "px";
        shape.style.height = height + "px";
        shape.style.left = x + "px";
        shape.style.top = y + "px";
        shape.style.backgroundColor = color;
        this.createHandle("handle-top", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-bottom", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-left", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-right", shape);
        // Add event listeners for drag and drop
        this.draggable(shape);

        this.container.appendChild(shape);
    },
    createHandle: function (handleClass, shape) {
        const handle = document.createElement("div");
        handle.classList.add("resizable-handle", handleClass);

        let isResizing = false;
        let startX, startY, startWidth, startHeight;

        const startResize = (e) => {
            isResizing = true;
            startX = e.clientX;
            startY = e.clientY;
            startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(shape).width);
            startHeight = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(shape).height);
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
        };

        const resize = (e) => {
            if (isResizing) {
                if (handleClass.includes("right")) {
                    shape.style.width = startWidth + e.clientX - startX + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("bottom")) {
                    shape.style.height = startHeight + e.clientY - startY + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("left")) {
                    const newWidth = startWidth + startX - e.clientX;
                    shape.style.width = newWidth + "px";
                    shape.style.left = startX - newWidth + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("top")) {
                    const newHeight = startHeight + startY - e.clientY;
                    shape.style.height = newHeight + "px";
                    shape.style.top = startY - newHeight + "px";
                }
            }
        };

        const stopResize = () => {
            isResizing = false;
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize);
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
        };

        handle.addEventListener("mousedown", startResize);
        shape.appendChild(handle);
    },
    draggable: function (element) {
        let isDragging = false;
        let offsetX, offsetY;

        element.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
            if (!this.resizing) {
                isDragging = true;
                const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
                offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left;
                offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
            if (isDragging) {
                const newX = e.clientX - offsetX;
                const newY = e.clientY - offsetY;
                element.style.left = newX + "px";
                element.style.top = newY + "px";
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
            isDragging = false;
        });
    }
};

const container = DrawJs.init("#container");

document.getElementById("rect-tool").addEventListener("click", () => {
    DrawJs.drawRectangle(100, 60, 300, 200, "#000");
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}
#container {
    width: calc(50vw);
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
#tool-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 14px;
}
.tool {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#rect-tool > div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
}
#circle-tool > div {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
}
#line-tool > div {
    width: 35px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background: #000;
}
#polygon-tool > div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 16px solid #000;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    transform: translateY(-25%);
}

.resizable-shape {
    position: absolute;
}

.resizable-handle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: none;
}
.resizable-shape:hover .resizable-handle {
    display: block;
}
.handle-top {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: ns-resize;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.handle-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: ns-resize;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.handle-left {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: ew-resize;
}

.handle-right {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<ul id="tool-wrapper">
            <li class="tool" id="rect-tool" title="rectangle">
                <div></div>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is non trivial. What is expected behaviour when clicking the black button? To create a rectangle inside the outline?

Comment: @mplungjan expectation: when drag event triggers the rectangle and the mouse cursor should be at the same position but I got rectangle in different position. just Try to drag the rectangle you will know the results

Comment: So at the mouse coordinates outside the bordered larger  box

Comment: I am not able to drag _anything_ in the rendered snippet.

Comment: @CBroe click the small box below. That will generate a rectangle and Try to drag that rectangle to see the draggable behaviour.

Comment: Because your #container has `position: relative`, it is the reference point for the absolute positioning of the `.resizable-shape` element you put into it. But the values you are calculating during the dragging, are relative to the viewport. So you will have to factor in the offset of your container to the viewport as well.

Comment: @CBroe I got it. But How can I calculate the values relative to #container.

Comment: Use getBoundingClientRect for the container as well, and subtract the top/left of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually everything was fine you just assumed that getBoundingClientRect() was equivalent to element.style.left/element.style.top

i've made some edit inside you "mousedown"

oh there was some minor bug on resizing too , i did some fix but still far from perfection ^_^
i hope this can help you have a nice day

```js
const DrawJs = {
    selectedShape: null,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    container: null,
    resizing: false,

    init: function (containerId) {
        const container = document.querySelector(containerId);
        this.container = container;
        return container;
    },

    drawRectangle: function (width, height, x, y, color) {
        const shape = document.createElement("div");
        shape.classList.add("resizable-shape");
        shape.style.width = width + "px";
        shape.style.height = height + "px";
        shape.style.left = x + "px";
        shape.style.top = y + "px";
        shape.style.backgroundColor = color;
        this.createHandle("handle-top", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-bottom", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-left", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-right", shape);
        // Add event listeners for drag and drop
        this.draggable(shape);

        this.container.appendChild(shape);
    },
    createHandle: function (handleClass, shape) {
        const handle = document.createElement("div");
        handle.classList.add("resizable-handle", handleClass);

        let isResizing = false;
        let startX, startY, startLeft, startTop, startWidth, startHeight;

        const startResize = (e) => {
            isResizing = true;
            //shape / element resizing sentinel was never set 
            // same for concept on stopResize()
            shape.resizing=true;
            startX = e.clientX;
            startY = e.clientY;
            startWidth = shape.offsetWidth;
            startHeight = shape.offsetHeight;
            //this are needed for a correct resizing
            startLeft = shape.offsetLeft;
            startTop = shape.offsetTop;
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
        };

        const resize = (e) => {
            if (isResizing) {
                if (handleClass.includes("right")) {
                    shape.style.width = startWidth + e.clientX - startX + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("bottom")) {
                    shape.style.height = startHeight + e.clientY - startY + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("left")) {
                    const newWidth = startWidth + startX - e.clientX;
                    shape.style.width = newWidth + "px";
                    //this fix a little bug... it's far from perfection
                    //we should handle max width 0 too
                    shape.style.left = e.clientX - (startX-startLeft) + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("top")) {
                    const newHeight = startHeight + startY - e.clientY;
                    shape.style.height = newHeight + "px";
                    //same concept above
                    shape.style.top = e.clientY - (startY-startTop) + "px";
                }
            }
        };

        const stopResize = () => {
            isResizing = false;
            //shape / element resizing sentinel was never set 
            // here we set resizing to false
            shape.resizing=false;
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize);
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
        };

        handle.addEventListener("mousedown", startResize);
        shape.appendChild(handle);
    },
    draggable: function (element) {
        let isDragging = false;
        let offsetX, offsetY;

        element.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
            // change this with element because it is not the same 
            //if (!this.resizing){
            if (!element.resizing) {
                //console.dir("eCli: "+e.clientX+" "+e.clientY);
                //console.dir("tSt: "+e.target.style.left+" "+e.target.style.top);
                //console.dir("tSt: "+e.target.offsetLeft+" "+e.target.offsetTop);
                //console.dir(e.target.getBoundingClientRect());
                
                //if you uncomment the above  log 
                // you can see that the value of style.left/style.top is different from getBoundingClientRect() result
                // you can use e.target.offetLeft adn e.target.offsetTop in replace
                isDragging = true;
                offsetX = e.clientX - element.offsetLeft;
                offsetY = e.clientY - element.offsetTop;
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
            if (isDragging) {
                const newX = e.clientX - offsetX;
                const newY = e.clientY - offsetY;
                element.style.left = newX + "px";
                element.style.top = newY + "px";
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
            isDragging = false;
        });
    }
};

const container = DrawJs.init("#container");

document.getElementById("rect-tool").addEventListener("click", () => {
    DrawJs.drawRectangle(100, 60, 300, 200, "#000");
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}
#container {
    width: calc(50vw);
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
#tool-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 14px;
}
.tool {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#rect-tool > div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
}
#circle-tool > div {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
}
#line-tool > div {
    width: 35px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background: #000;
}
#polygon-tool > div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 16px solid #000;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    transform: translateY(-25%);
}

.resizable-shape {
    position: absolute;
}

.resizable-handle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: none;
}
.resizable-shape:hover .resizable-handle {
    display: block;
}
.handle-top {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: ns-resize;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.handle-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: ns-resize;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.handle-left {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: ew-resize;
}

.handle-right {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<ul id="tool-wrapper">
            <li class="tool" id="rect-tool" title="rectangle">
                <div></div>
            </li>
</ul>
```